# Bootstrap Full Page Slider Autoplay doesn`t work with more than 3 pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the website I am currently working on there seems to be a problem with the full page slider from starbootstrap.com: When just replacing the placeholders with images all works fine however when adding a fourth item to the slideshow the autoplay stops working.

Here`s what I did: *I added a fourth li-tag.*

```
 <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel">
        </li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    </ol>
```

*Copied the Item with new image*

```
 <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the fourth background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style=
            "background-image:url('images/index/4.JPG');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1.5s">
                <!--Caption-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

*added Javascript to the bottom, just before the close-body tag*

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.carousel').carousel({
         interval: 5000
     })
});
</script>
```

Now as mentioned before this works perfectly with only three items in the slider, but as soon as I make the written changes autoplay stops working...
All the other items look exactly the same as the "fourth item".

I really can`t figuer out what the error is, there are no js-errors in the console...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If I have your `"wow fadeIn"` div it takes over a minute before autoplay starts. If I replace it with `<h2>Caption 4</h2>`, autoplay starts in a few seconds.

Comment: Your jQuery snippet target isn't valid. There are no `.carousel` items in your HTML to target. Might be a good spot to investigate.

Comment: can you please share your Fiddle here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write proper structure.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

and use `<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="true">`

source from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)
hope this will help you.